# How to make base64 image and insert for any api service using model class in Angular 5

Tags: angular, api, base64

I have a question base64 image issue.I think  a lot of sources are not clearly at this issue. How can we make base64 image method and how can we insert our rest api using Angular 5. What is the type of image in our model class such as string,number,any etc. ? Now , i have a simple example but i don't know wheter it warks correctly. Could you help  at this issue ? Maybe another Angular Developper take advantage of this sharing.

Example Model Class

```
export class Bank {bankLogo: any;} // what is the type?
```

Example Component

```
export class BankComponent implements OnInit {
              public bankLogo:any;
              bank: Bank[];
              private imageSrc: string = '';
               //My Example Function 
              handleInputChange(e) {
                    var file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.target.files[0];
                    var pattern = /image-*/;
                    var reader = new FileReader();
              if (!file.type.match(pattern)) {
                      alert('invalid format');
                      return;
                    }
                    reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }
                   _handleReaderLoaded(e) {
                    let reader = e.target;
                    this.imageSrc = reader.result;
                    console.log(this.imageSrc)
                  }
              Create() {
              const newPost: Bank = new Bank();     
              newPost.bankLogo=this.bankLogo;
              this.bankService.CreateUser(newPost).subscribe((resp: Bank) => {
          console.log(resp); this.bank.push(resp);
        });
      }
              constructor(private bankService: BankService) { }
}
```

Example Html

```
<div class="image-upload col-md-9 mb-5 mt-5">
          <img [src]="imageSrc" style="max-width:300px;max-height:300px"/>
          <input name="imageUrl" type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="handleInputChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="bankLogo" />
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want to generate the base64-string? In the backend or the frontend?

Comment: ı will use front-end side and ı am going to use it  for restful api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic approach to this topic. Hope this helps for a start.

Use a fileChooser that reacts on change-events:

```
<input type="file" id="fileChooser" (change)="changeHandler($event)" />
```

The change handler in your typescript file then reads in the image and stores
it as base64 string in a variable.

```
private image: string;

...

changeHandler(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event: any) => {
            this.image = event.target['result'];
            this.logger.info(this.image);
        };

        // .readAsDataURL() directly converts the image into a base64 string
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

    }
}
```

Show the image in HTML

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url('+ image +')' | safeStyle"
     [style.background-repeat]="'no-repeat'"
     [style.background-size]="'100% 100%'">
</div>
```

You'll probably have to use a Sanitizer Pipe. Otherwise the browser will prevent you from showing the image.

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeStyle' })
export class SafeStylePipe {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(html);
  }
}
```

This little example should give you the possibility to read in an image as base64 string and directly show it.

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem.